# Question about may and might

Tags: difference

You may go now if you want to.

You might go now if you want to.
I heard this and I become curious that which is correct
Please let me know this.

Comment: Depending on what you mean, on how possible the action of the following verb is, both can be correct. Without stating what you intend to mean, your question **may not** survive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of your lines, "you may go if you want" indicates allowing like "you're allowed to go if you want" and the second line "you might go now if you want to" doesn't really make sense if you ask me, because it's more of a possibility

speaking of which, here's some info about may and might from Practical English Usage which I hope you find useful, but a personal tip, just take a look at the examples and that'll do it

We often use *may* and *might* to talk about the chance (possibility) that something will happen, or is happening.

*We may go climbing in the Alps next summer.*

*‘I think Labour are going to win.’ ‘You may be right.’*

*Daniel might phone. If he does, ask him to ring later.*

*‘Where’s Emma?’ ‘I don’t know. She might be out running, I suppose.’*

*May well*, *might well* and *could well* suggest stronger possibilities.

*‘I think it’s going to rain.’ ‘You may well be right – the sky’s really black.’*

*Might* is not often used as the past form of *may*: more often it is used to talk about the present or future. *Might* is less definite or more hesitant than *may*, suggesting a smaller chance – they are used when people think something is possible but not very likely. Compare:

*I may go to London tomorrow. (perhaps a 50% chance)*

*Joe might come with me. (perhaps a 30% chance)*